# Function using a class as a parameter

Tags: c++

I am having trouble with the function:

```
double area( const Point & a, const Point & b, const Point & c );
```

The instructions for this function are :

Area is a non-member function that does a calculation with its 3 Point args. Specifically, it computes and returns the area of a triangle with vertices represented by the 3 Points.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank You!

```
# include <string>
# include <iostream>
# include <cmath>
using namespace std;

class Point{
    public:
        Point( double x = 0, double y = 0 );
        double getX() const;
        double getY() const;
        Point & setX( double x );    //  mutator, returning reference to self
        Point & setY( double y );
        const Point & output() const;
        double distance( const Point & other ) const;
    private:
        double myX;
        double myY;
    };
double area( const Point & a, const Point & b, const Point & c );

int main (){


    Point a;
    Point b;
    Point c;

    a.setX (2);
    a.setY (0);
    b.setX (0);     
    b.setY (1);
    c.setX (0);
    c.setY (0);


    system ("pause");

}//main

Point :: Point( double x, double y){
    setX (x);
    setY (y);
}// ctr
 double Point :: getX() const{
    return myX;
}//getX
double Point :: getY() const{
    return myY;
}//getY
Point & Point :: setX( double x ){
    myX = x;
    return *this;
}//setX
Point & Point :: setY( double y ){
    myY = y;
    return *this;
}//setY
const Point & Point :: output() const{
    cout << "(" << myX << "," << myY << ")" << endl;
    return *this;
}//output
double Point :: distance( const Point & other ) const{
    double d;
    d = sqrt(pow(other.myX-myX,2)+pow(other.myY-myY,2));
    return d;
}//distance

double area( const Point & a, const Point & b, const Point & c ){

    Point area;

    double length1, length2, length3;
    double s, area1;
    length1 = sqrt(pow(a.getX-b.getX,2)+pow(a.getY-b.getY,2));
    length2 = sqrt(pow(b.getX-c.getX,2)+pow(b.getY-c.getY,2));
    length3 = sqrt(pow(a.getX-c.getX,2)+pow(a.getY-c.getY,2));

    s = (length1+length2+length3)/2;


    area1 = sqrt(s*(s-length1)(s-length2)(s-length3));

return area1;

}//area
```

Comment: What behaviour are you seeing?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a problem in your code since you omit **`()`** when calling `Point`'s methods in `area` function, e.g.

> ```
> length1 = sqrt(pow(a.getX-b.getX,2)+pow(a.getY-b.getY,2));
> length2 = sqrt(pow(b.getX-c.getX,2)+pow(b.getY-c.getY,2));
> length3 = sqrt(pow(a.getX-c.getX,2)+pow(a.getY-c.getY,2));
> ```

You should use `a.getX()`, `b.getX()`, etc.

Comment: I am also having a problem with 
    area1 = sqrt(s*((s-length1)(s-length2)(s-length3)));

I am getting error : error C2064: term does not evaluate to a function taking 1 arguments

Comment: In C++ juxtaposition does not imply multiplication - you need explicit `*`s anywhere you are multiplying

Comment: @user2802707 if the answer helps you, upvote the answer. If you think its the definitive answer, mark it as answer (The green check).

Comment: On the other hand, he is new so could spend millions of years until he comes here again, or directly he will never return...